# blender outline window: how to undo shift + A?

Tags: interface, outliner

The outliner now expands every single item. I make a very long expanded structure. I missed typed <kbd>shift</kbd>–<kbd>A</kbd>, then every thing collapsed to a single entry.

I want to make it back.

How do I make it back to unfolded state?

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>shift</kbd>–<kbd>A</kbd> is a shortcut in the outliner.  It executes the *Expand/Collapse All* command.  That command is a toggle, meaning that repeating the operation undoes it.

If the outliner is collapsed down to a single entry then <kbd>shift</kbd>–<kbd>A</kbd> will open up the entire view.

If the outliner is open up, showing every entry, then <kbd>shift</kbd>–<kbd>A</kbd> will collapse it down.

Note that pressing <kbd>shift</kbd>–<kbd>A</kbd> after you've collapsed it to a single entry doesn't exactly undo the collapse because the outliner doesn't remember what entries you had already expanded.  Expand gets you *every* entry updated.

<kbd>shift</kbd>–<kbd>A</kbd> is a keymap entry.  If you want to use a different key or just don't want <kbd>shift</kbd>–<kbd>A</kbd> to work that way, you can edit your preferences, go to the *Keymap* tab, and search for "exp".  This will show you the entry that you can edit:

[image: keymap search showing the expand/collapse all shortcut]

If you click on the x then the shortcut is removed.  You may have to click *Save Preferences* if you want this to work.

Answer (score 0):

Just press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> again to fold everything.

Comment: no, I did not downvote your answer, in case you were wondering.  I didn't even flag it.